# Is the limit of this expression $1$?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Can you help me to determine if the limit of this expression is unity?

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{2n + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{ 2n}{B_{2n}}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Where $B_{2n}$ is the [Bernoulli Number](http://www.bernoulli.org/) of $2n$. I have tried this calculation using Wolfram Alpha, but the computation is very expensive, so I have not calculated beyond $n=400$. The values alternate between $y > 1$ and $y < 1$ as $n$ increases, but seem to stick close to $0.995374$ after about 100. This is related to a possible corollary of the Riemann Hypothesis.

Namaste!

Comment: FYI, the mathematical part of the answer below (after the line) does not hold water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not $1$, I'm pretty sure.

If we can show that the modulus of the terms decreases, then the alternating series test says that the error of the alternating series is at most the first omitted term.
Evaluating the summand at $n=10$ yields approximately $-0.000318184$; so the error after $n=9$ is at most that value.
The sum after $n=9$ is approximately $-0.9950809$, which is not $0.0003$ away from $-1$.

So we just need it decreasing; it turns out to be decreasing for $n>3$, which you can see heuristically as follows (assuming the approximation holds sufficiently well for some $n \leq 10$). Very strictly I haven't proved this, but I'd be absolutely shocked if it weren't true. The argument above works fine if you can show that $\frac{n}{(2n+1) B_n}$ is decreasing for all $n > M$, some $M \leq 9$.

---

The Bernoulli numbers grow as $$B_{2n} \sim (-1)^{n-1} 4 \sqrt {\pi n} \left( \frac n {\pi e} \right)^{2n}$$
So your summand is roughly $$\frac{2n}{4 \sqrt{2}} \times \frac{1}{2n+1} \times \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (\pi e)^{2n}}{4 \times n^{2n} \sqrt{\pi n}}$$
which is in modulus $$\frac{2n}{4 \sqrt{2}} \times \frac{1}{2n+1} \times \frac{(\pi e)^{2n}}{4 \times n^{2n} \sqrt{\pi n}} \leq \frac{1}{16 \sqrt{2}} \times \frac{(\pi e)^{2n}}{n^{2n} \sqrt{\pi n}}$$

This is decreasing in $n$ for $n>3$.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your reply. I have made a correction in the above formula, does this change your assessment in any way?

Comment: @InLak'ech You've just pulled the constant $\sqrt{2}$ out of the sum. The expression has the same value now as it did before.

Comment: Thanks, your analysis (and a sampling of the values for n through 13) seems to confirm that the ratio is decreasing and heading towards -0.995374 instead of unity.

Comment: The $\le$ at the end makes the fact that the last ratio is decreasing, quite useless since the alternating series criterion could apply to the sequence of equivalents and not to the sequence itself. Please repair this last step. Even before that, equivalents of $B_{2n}$ certainly do not suffice...